# Add Custom Column in DataTable jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there a way to add a custom column to DataTable jQuery plugin, such that I can handle its click even in jQuery to do some other tasks like loading another Grid below the one display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can just add anything inside a td and handle the click event,

in your markup

```
<table id="datatable">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="handle_click">click me</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

in your js

```
    $("#handle_click").click(function(e){
//do whatever here
});
```

Comment: Are you assuming Table present? Is there a programmatic way to add a column? Thanks

Comment: I did a small search, I can prepare my table dynamically then select it by attaching DataTable() plugin. It works fine. Thanks